# Assume roles during AWS CDK to issue boto3 calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to issue boto3 calls during the stack creation using AWS CDK. This is a requirement before the cloudformation stack is created.

When the stack is executed in a container then the container privileges take care of this and it is not an issue.

However, duing my SDLC process the development evironment is created from the command line.

When I execute the CDK with --verbose option I get the following logs

```
[13:06:57] Checking for previously published assets
[13:06:57] Retrieved account ID xxxxxxxxxxxx from disk cache
[13:06:57] Assuming role 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-xxxxxxxxxxxx-eu-west-1'.
[13:06:57] Retrieved account ID xxxxxxxxxxxx from disk cache
[13:06:57] Assuming role 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-xxxxxxxxxxxx-eu-west-1'.
[13:06:57] Retrieved account ID xxxxxxxxxxxx from disk cache
[13:06:57] Assuming role 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/cdk-hnb659fds-deploy-role-xxxxxxxxxxxx-eu-west-1'.
```

How does this assumption of role happen. Further more cdk has multiple roles which are assumed as required. What is the api available to assume these roles.

Alternatively, there is a --profile aws-profile passed from command line; how can I get this value on the app.py and pass this down to the other modules

Answer (score 0):

I googled a lot and also had conversations with AWS support.

The only way to do this is to add the profile in the context within cdk.json or pass this as a parameter.

It is very surprising that AWS is not opening this area with API's.